# Prove that if the series $\sum u_n$ converges, than $\sum \frac{ \sqrt{u_n} }{n + 1} $ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $(u_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a positive sequence.
>
> We consider the sequence:  $v_n = \frac{ \sqrt{u_n} }{n + 1}$
>
> 1. Prove that if the series $\sum u_n$ converges, than $\sum v_n $ converges.
> 2. Prove that the opposite is not true.

---

1. We have: $v_n = \frac{ \sqrt{u_n} }{n + 1} \leq \sqrt{u_n} \leq u_n \implies 
   \sum v_n \leq \sum u_n$.

By comparison test, $\sum u_n $ converges, so does $\sum v_n$.

2. I could not find a counter-example to prove the opposite is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually $\sqrt[]{u_n} \leq u_n$ is wrong (does it hold $u_n=1/2$ for instance?). Better is to use [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality. It is straightforward so I leave it up to you.

For a counter example take 
$$u_n=\frac{1}{1+n}$$

Comment: $\sum v_n \leq \sum \sqrt{u_n} \leq  ( \sum u^2_n)^{ \frac{1}{2}} $. Since $\sum u_n$ converges, so does $\sum u^2_n$. And then I can use the comparison test to show $\sum v_n$ converges. Is it correct?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi no, you can apply Cauchy-Schwarz at the beginning already to get $$\sum v_n = \sum\frac{1} {1+n} \cdot \sqrt[] {u_n} \leq \sqrt[] {\left(\sum \frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\right) \left(\sum u_n\right)} $$ both of the series on the right converge, so...?

Comment: It would be incorrect if I removed $\frac{1}{n + 1}$ ?

Comment: I don't see how you are applying Cauchy Schwarz in your comment... You apply it incorrectly.

Comment: Ah! I did not pay attention to that. Thank you for help. Accepted answer.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Try $u_n=\frac{1}{n}$. It works.

Comment: Thank you. My reasoning for question 1 is correct?

Comment: Got confused at first. As Shashi explained it isn't correct. $u_n$ converges to $0$ so the square roots are actually bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Use $ab \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$.
$$v_n = \frac{1}{1+n} \cdot \sqrt[] {u_n} \leq \frac{1}{2}\bigg(u_n +\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg).$$

Answer (score 0):

Now, we arrive at the divergence test: If $\sum\frac{\sqrt{u_n}}{n+1}$ diverges, then series $\sum u_n$ diverges.